# Running Multiple CMS server and Multiple Topology Managers

Tags: content-manager, topology-manager, clustering, scalability

We have two Clustered CMS server Web8.5 created the 1st CMS server much earlier than the second server, and I am suspecting that the second server was pointing to different DB when it was created, so The Content Manager ID could have been different for the two CMS servers, we are facing Topology manager issues where the second server is not recognizing any mapping that's already functioning in the 1st Server.

Refer to this [doc](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-33187D11-0B59-4ABB-A67E-C448FD952F04&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-974EFAAF-DC86-4541-8025-A9ECE4796424.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-33187D11-0B59-4ABB-A67E-C448FD952F04&url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL%20Web-v5%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dtopology%2520manager&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1519745174360&currentQuery=topology%2520manager&currentScope=)
Specifically this paragraph:

"ID for this Content Manager server
By default, the installer proposes to give the Content Manager server an ID that is identical to the ID of the Content Manager database. This ensures that all Content Manager servers in a scaled-out setup have the same ID. You can choose to override the default, but if you do so and if you are scaling out Content Manager, you must ensure yourself that all Content Manager instances have the same ID."

My question, where is that ID located, I need to verify that my two servers have the same ID, and if they don't I need to synchronize them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Content Manager ID stored in the System Environment Variables:

```
TRIDION_CM_ENVIRONMENT_ID = TridionCM_localhost
```

To see the Content Manager environment setting:

Gets one or all Content Manager Environments from the Topology Manager.

**Get-TtmCmEnvironment**

```
CoreServiceRootUrl     : net.tcp://localhost:2660
WebsiteRootUrl         : http://localhost:80
CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"MTSUser", "Password":"xxxx"
Id                     : TridionCM_localhost
ExtensionProperties    : {}
```

Updates an existing Content Manager Environment in the Topology Manager.

**Syntax**

```
Set-TtmCmEnvironment -Id <String> [-WebsiteRootUrl <String>] [-CoreServiceRootUrl <String>] [-AuthenticationType <Nullable`1[AuthenticationType]>] [-ExtensionProperties <Hashtable>] [-TtmServiceUrl <String>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

Deletes a Content Manager Environment from the Topology Manager.

**Syntax**

```
Remove-TtmCmEnvironment [-Id] <String> [-Force <SwitchParameter>] [-TtmServiceUrl <String>] [-WhatIf <SwitchParameter>] [-Confirm <SwitchParameter>] [<CommonParameters>]
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

@Ashraf, the CM Environment ID is stored in the Topology Manager Database.  So as long as your two clustered CM servers are connecting to the same Topology Manager database, it should have the same CM Environment ID.

The `%TRIDION_HOME%\Topology Manager\web\web.config` contains the database setting
Note: The database setting is encrypted so you will need to decrypt it before seeing the info.